# Is it safe to use a quick disconnect on a regulator?

Tags: co2

I would like to replace the barb fitting on the low-pressure side of my dual-guage regulator with a female quick-dissconnect. I would attach the male part of the disconnect to the gas line.

I'm not sure how to describe the style of quick disconnect I have on-hand, so here's a picture:

[image: quick disconnect]

Is this as leak-proof as the traditional barb fitting with hose clamp?

For those who care, here's why I want to do this. I ferment in a 10 gallon Cornelius keg. When the fermentation is done, I move the beer to a 5 gallon serving keg. I move it by pushing with CO<sub>2</sub>. Since I only have a single CO<sub>2</sub> tank and regular, I have to disconnect the gas line from the regulator so I can move the  tank and hook up a different gas line.

Over time, the gas line starts to widen out where it's pushed over the barb. To maintain a tight seal, I have to continually trim the gas line, removing the widened out section. A quick disconnect would solve this problem nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, quick-disconnects such as this are entirely reliable for what you propose. In fact, it's more often than not that the hose barbs the QD's are connected to are what fails, rather than the QD's themselves. Safety-wise, it's no different than having anything else attached to the low-pressure side of your regulator. Anything beyond the on-off valve (which I assume you would keep) shouldn't be able to retain an unsafe amount of pressure.

If I could offer one suggestion, it would be to install a length of hose between the regulator and the female QD, enough so you can freely maneuver the two couplers together when connecting. I find it tricky to retract the sleeve on the female side when it's either fixed or too close to something else.

Comment: The male QD does not stop flow of gas out the regulator automatically so you would have to turn off the gas every time you go to disconnect your hose. If you look at nearly any commercial air compressor out there, the hoses have the male end and the compressors have the female end for this reason.

Comment: That's a good point. The female couplers are also about three times as expensive so it doesn't make sense to have to buy more than one of them. Editing my suggestion so it is slightly more useful..